# post is not showing in browser while saving in databaser :laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I m working on showing a post, when i post data with the image then my data stored in DB (image is also storing into destination folder) but not showing on the browser, here is the code of the page(index.blade.php) on which m trying to show post:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <form method="POST" action="{{url('posts')}}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <!--@if(session('message'))
          {{session('messgae')}}
         @endif-->
         @if(count($errors) > 0)
         <ul>
              @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                   <li>{{$error}}</li>
              @endforeach
         </ul>
         @endif
         {{csrf_field()}}
          Name:- <input type="text" name="title" value="{{old('title')}}">
          Text:- <textarea name="body">value="{{old('body')}"></textarea>
          Upload File:- <input type="file" name="thumbnail" value="{{old('thumbnail')}}">
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
@endsection
```

this is post controller

```
public function store(Request $request)    
{

    if($request->hasFile('thumbnail') && $request->thumbnail->isValid())
    {
        $extension = $request->thumbnail->extension();
        $filename = time()."_.".$extension;
        $request->thumbnail->move(public_path('images'), $filename);
    }
    else
    {
        $filename = 'code.png';
    }

    \App\Post::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'body' => $request->body,
        'thumbnail' => $filename,
    ]);

    return redirect('posts');
}
```

Comment: what error you are gtting

Comment: nthing just blank page

Comment: Have you checked logs?

Comment: yeah data is storing in db and also pic is moving from source to destination

Answer (score 1):

I found a mistake in your code

```
@foreach($posts as post)
```

use

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
```

Comment: still same issue

Comment: can you show your controller code or dd($posts) in your controller before return view